# Data type issues with CRM OData/REST calls (JSON)

Tags: javascript, json, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to clone records in CRM using javascript. I'm following the code similar to this article ----
**[clone records](http://thinkingincrm.blogspot.in/2013/07/clone-record-via-javascript-crm-2011.html).**

I get the following error where there are 'boolean' type fields in the record. Can someone please suggest how to parse/modify the data to get rid of this error?

Incorrect attribute value type **System.Data.Services.Serializers.JsonReader+JsonObjectRecords**

When I debug the code the value for the boolean attribute is coming as **true** or **false** and i'm passing it as is (no formatting).

I have tried replacing the boolean value with value.toString() or even new Boolean(value) and it didn't work.

---

LOG:

```
{
   "__metadata":{
      "uri":"http:///POC /XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/okn_dealSet(guid'b0ede4ab-15c9-e311-94e1-00155d000854')",
      "type":"Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.okn_deal"
   },
   "okn_name":"Go boolean",
   "new_allowemail":true,
   "TimeZoneRuleVersionNumber":0,
   "OwningBusinessUnit":{
      "__metadata":{
         "type":"Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.EntityReference"
      },
      "Id":"b229bd07-d2be-e311-b028-00155d000854",
      "LogicalName":"businessunit",
      "Name":null
   },
   "UTCConversionTimeZoneCode":null,
   "OwningUser":{
      "__metadata":{
         "type":"Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.EntityReference"
      },
      "Id":"f8d8b780-a4a2-e311-b51b-00155d000854",
      "LogicalName":"systemuser",
      "Name":null
   },
   "OwningTeam":{
      "__metadata":{
         "type":"Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.EntityReference"
      },
      "Id":null,
      "LogicalName":null,
      "Name":null
   },
   "okn_type":{
      "__metadata":{
         "type":"Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.OptionSetValue"
      },
      "Value":200000001
   }
}
```

**Edit**

I have also encountered the same issue when i used the date formatting function from [**SDK**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309549.aspx). The date value was coming like this : 
    "okn_startdate":{},

```
_dateReviver: function (key, value) {
 ///<summary>
  /// Private function to convert matching string values to Date objects.
  ///</summary>
  ///<param name="key" type="String">
  /// The key used to identify the object property
  ///</param>
  ///<param name="value" type="String">
  /// The string value representing a date
  ///</param>
  var a;
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
   a = /Date\(([-+]?\d+)\)/.exec(value);
   if (a) {
    return new Date(parseInt(value.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
   }
  }
  return value;
 },
```

Comment: Could you please provide the JSON that is send to the server.

Comment: I have added an image in the post now. please take a look when you get a chance.

Comment: You simply could write 'console.log(JSON.stringify(cloneData, replacer))' in first 'success' part. Maybe you also post your source code.

Comment: thanks, posted some content of the console.log result. and the source code is almost the same as the article I referred above. would you still like me to post it ?

Comment: Your JSON seems to be okay. Where do you get the error in your code? In the second 'error: function' in the ajax call? How does the JSON look if you didnt have the boolean attribute?

Comment: Yes, the error is from the second error: function in ajax. Even if the  boolean attribute is present in the entity and it has a 'null' value, the code works fine. I have updated issue with the date format as well.

Comment: Update - it looks like the error was due to one of the if conditions. I think the data contains an entry with empty 'key' and 'value' with all the elements. Once I updated the code to exclude the checks for that empty key, value pair the issue was resolved.